# Sending JPEG NSData over TCP to Python server

Tags: tcp, jpeg, twisted, nsdata, nsoutputstream

I have a Python tcp server that has a iOS client.  It is able to send data and receive, the only issue I am having is likely with encoding.  I am trying to send a JPEG through TCP to the Python server and write the data to a JPEG on the server.  The jpeg keeps corrupting.

Client Obj-C code:

```
[self.stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection
                                                           completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

            NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
            UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
                                                               iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];


                                                               [iv setFrame:[[self view]frame]];





                                                               ConnectionManager *netCon = [ConnectionManager alloc];
                                                               conMan = netCon;
                                                               [conMan initNetworkCommunication];



                                                               [conMan.outputStream write:(const uint8_t *)[imageData bytes] maxLength:[imageData length]];



        }];
```

And here is the python (twisted) server code:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
from twisted.internet import reactor

class IphoneChat(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.clients.append(self)
        print "clients are ", self.factory.clients

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        file = open('test.jpeg','w')

        file.write(data)
        file.close()


factory = Factory()

factory.clients=[]


factory.protocol = IphoneChat
reactor.listenTCP(2000, factory)
print "Iphone Chat server started"
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP is a stream-oriented protocol.  It doesn't have messages (therefore it doesn't have stable message boundaries).  `dataReceived` is called with some bytes - at least one, but how many more than that you can't really know.

You can't just treat whatever is passed to `dataReceived` as the complete image data.  It is some bytes from the image data.  Chances are `dataReceived` will be called repeatedly, each time with some more bytes from the image data.  You have to re-assemble the data passed to these multiple calls into the complete image data.